# It is a question about a property of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Does any antichain in a Euclidean space have Lebesgue measure zero?

Here *antichain* refers to the product partial order $\preceq$ on $\Bbb R^n$: $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\preceq\langle y_1,\ldots,y_n\rangle$ iff $x_k\le y_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: Antichain with respect to what order?

Comment: x>y if all components of x is greater then the respective components of y. D is an anti-chain if for any x, y in D, neither x>y nor y>x

Comment: So you want the product partial order based on the usual linear order in $\Bbb R$. Okay.